# learning ASP.NET 3.5 free source code web applications

Tags: asp.net

I need to know websites that produce free source code for famouse web application

Comment: Depending on the comments you provided on the answers provided. What exactly do you want to learn? Are you searching for something specific?

Comment: @xlll i mean famouse application how to use videos streams as youtube
and how to set my site very secure etc..i need project where i can trace it for more learning

Answer (score 3):

To name a few:

- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/)
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com/)

Comment: i need sample of web applications for learning

Comment: What aspect of web programming you would like to learn?

Comment: security,videos strems ,routing ,site maps,chat systems etc i mean project cover many technologies .where can i trace source code for more learning

Answer (score 1):

You can find some great web applications in Codeplex, for example:

- [Nerddinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)
- [Oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @cd thanks put i need it for learning

Comment: http://www.orchardproject.net/. I believe Oxite's set aside for the Orchard project.